# PHP sql not getting output

Tags: php, sql

For some reason i am not getting an output from this code. Specifically from this if statement: 
I inserted an html tag with a test word, but it never appeared on the output. 
I fixed the "SELECT" typo.. still getting same results.. no output.. i think the problem is from this statement.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
```

I inserted another test phrase right before it - success and another one right after it - didn't output

```
        if($sel=="getinfo"){
                    try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows = $db->exec("SEEELECT * FROM fminformationtable WHERE FM_ID = '$_POST[iden]'"); 
                    ?>
                    test
                    <?php
                    }
```

This is the full function

```
    if($sel=="addnew"){
    try {
                $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $rows=$db->query("INSERT INTO fminformationtable 
                VALUES('$_POST[iden]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[office]','$_POST[ext]','$_POST[hphone]','$_POST[mobile]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[syear]','$_POST[tyear]','$_POST[ldegree]','$_POST[ofrom]','$_POST[dyear]','$_POST[rinterest]')");

            }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {
            ?>
            <p>Your information has been submitted! </p>
            <?php
            }
            if($sel=="update"){


                try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



                    $rows=$db->query("UPDATE fminformationtable SET
                     Office=`$_POST[office]`,
                     Extension=`$_POST[ext]`,
                     HomePhone=`$_POST[hphone]',
                     MobilePhone=`$_POST[mobile]`,
                     Adress=`$_POST[address]`,
                     Email=`$_POST[email]`,
                     StartingYear=`$_POST[syear]`,
                     TerminationYrear=`$_POST[tyear]`,
                     LatestDegree=`$_POST[ldegree]`,
                     ObtainedFrom=`$_POST[ofrome]`,
                     DegreeYear=`$_POST[dyear]`,
                     ResearchInterest=`$_POST[rinterest]`

                    ");

                    }


                catch (PDOException $ex) {


                }
        }
        }
         if($sel=="delete"){
            try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows = $db->exec("DELETE FROM fminformationtable WHERE FM_ID = '$_POST[iden]'"); 


            }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }
        }

        if($sel=="getinfo"){
                    try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows = $db->exec("SEEELECT * FROM fminformationtable WHERE FM_ID = '$_POST[iden]'"); 
                    ?>
                    test
                    <?php
                    }
```

Comment: `SEEELECT` might be a typo ... it throws, which is never caught!

Comment: And injecting a `POST` variable directly in the query is a huge mistake. You need to read up on sql injection. As you are already using PDO, switching to prepared statements with bound variables is easy.

Comment: @EugenRieck, hmm, yes, I believe that is it.

Comment: `$rows = $db->exec("SEEELECT *...` is that a typo?

Comment: A side note, like @jeroen said, injecting a `POST` directly in your statment is a huge no-no  ...  No pun intended .. Or is there?

Answer (score 2):

1. You're using backticks instead of single quotes.
2. You never once check your function returns to see if they've failed.
3. You're using `try` with empty `catch` blocks to simply discard any information that might be useful to know. For instance, the errors that are causing your code to not return any data.
4. `SEEEELECT` isn't a MySQL operation.
5. You can't expand array indexes inside a double-quoted string unless you use `{$array['index']}`

Suggestion: Write your code in chunks of 1-3 lines, test it, write another chunk, test it, and so on. This code looks like it's been written all in one untested shot.

Also: yadda yadda SQL injection, parameterized queries, and so on.